# использование OpenAcc в Windows

Tags: windows, gcc

Вопрос по OpenAcc.
Почему-то кусок кода :

```
#include <openacc.h>
...
#define NSZ (1<<16)
...
//#pragma acc kernels

for (i=0; i<NSZ; i++)
  C[i]=A[i]+B[i];
```

c директивой ...kernels выполняется на 20% .. 15%
медлинее чем без нее

компилируется с опциями 
gcc -fopenacc -msse2 ...

примерно тот же код с использованием OpenCl выполняется в 1.5..2 раза быстрее
версия компилятора 5.1.0
Видеокарта NVIDIA GT 950
Что-то делаю не так?

Еще бы хотелось получить ссылки на рускоязычные докуметы по использованю GPU
с примерами (OpenAcc, OpenCl ну и др. ...)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа пытается сделать примерно следующее.

1. Передать 2 массива в видеокарту
2. Быстро сложить их на стороне видеокарты
3. Передать 1 массив обратно оттуда

Как видно, на шагах 1 и 3 массивы все равно обрабатываются последовательно. В итоге экономия достигается только за счет ускорения операции сложения - но у центрального процессора она и так быстрая (быстрее сложения только сдвиги на 1).

Вот и получается, что накладные расходы могут даже превысить выгоду от использования видеокарты.

Для того, чтобы получить настоящее ускорение - надо делать более сложные вычисления или передавать меньше данных.

А для таких простых циклов лучше применять векторизацию (mmx, sse и пр.) Возможно, ускорение на OpenCl вы получили именно из-за этих техник (тут я, к сожалению, не специалист).

К примеру, вам может подойти [`_mm_add_epi32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09xs4fkk(v=vs.90).aspx)